# The set $\omega$-accumulation points is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be topological spaces and $A\subseteq X$. How can we prove that the set of $\omega$-accumulation points of A, which is $A^{\omega}=\{x\in X \mid G\cap A \text{ is infinite for every open neighborhood $G$ of $x$}\}$, is closed?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: a closed set is a set with open complement. What is the complement of $A^\omega$? Is it open?

Comment: Indeed, I want to show that there is a open set $G$ such that $G \subseteq (A^{\omega})^{c}$, for every $x\in (A^{\omega})^{c}$. But, i couldn't.